# Develop A Browser Based Application in Python

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7

I have made a sqlite-database using Python. I wanted to know how to make a browser based offline application in Python or Javascript to connect to that sqlite-local-database and execute queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) may be an easy-to-learn solution, the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) will be enough to achieve what you want to do.